# Shadow/Remove string interpolator

Tags: scala, implicit, http4s

I'm using two libraries which define string interpolators (simplified code for clarity):

[Http4s](https://http4s.org/v0.21/api/org/http4s/syntax/literalsops):

```
implicit class LiteralsOps(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def uri(args: Any*): Uri = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.uriInterpolator
  (...)
  def ipv4(args: Any*): Uri.Ipv4Address = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipv4AddressInterpolator
  def ipv6(args: Any*): Uri.Ipv6Address = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipv6AddressInterpolator
}
```

[ip4s](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/com/comcast/ip4s-core_2.12/1.1.1/ip4s-core_2.12-1.1.1-javadoc.jar/!/com/comcast/ip4s/package$$IpLiteralSyntax.html):

```
implicit class IpLiteralSyntax(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def ip(args: Any*): IpAddress = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipInterpolator
  def ipv4(args: Any*): Ipv4Address = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipv4Interpolator
  def ipv6(args: Any*): Ipv6Address = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipv6Interpolator
  (...)
  def host(args: Any*): Hostname = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.hostnameInterpolator
}
```

I want to use them both, namely the `uri` interpolator from Http4s and the various interpolators from ip4s. The problem is that the following code:

```
import com.comcast.ip4s._
import org.http4s.syntax.literals._

class Foo(cidr: Cidr[Ipv4Address] = ipv4"192.168.1.1" / 24)
```

Fails to compile with:

```
[error] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method IpLiteralSyntax in package ip4s of type (sc: StringContext): com.comcast.ip4s.package.IpLiteralSyntax
[error]  and method http4sLiteralsSyntax in trait LiteralsSyntax of type (sc: StringContext): org.http4s.syntax.LiteralsOps
[error]  are possible conversion functions from StringContext to ?{def ipv4: ?}
[error]   class Foo(cidr: Cidr[Ipv4Address] = ipv4"192.168.1.1" / 24)
```

Is there anyway to shadow/remove a string interpolator from the implicit scope?

Comment: That would prevent me from using the ipv4 interpolator from ip4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is obviously that there are conflicting interpolators for `ipv4` and `ipv6` and compiler doesn't know which one to use.

Conflicting implicits problem can be solved by giving one of implicits higher priority. This can be done by using putting a [lower-priority implicits into a trait and then extend an object, that declares higher-priority implicits](https://gist.github.com/retronym/228673).

Implicits from `http4s` can be brought into scope with trait `AllSyntax`:

```
import com.comcast.ip4s._
import org.http4s.Uri
import org.http4s.syntax.AllSyntax

case class Foo(cidr: Cidr[Ipv4Address] = ipv4"192.168.1.1" / 24)

class MyApp extends AllSyntax {

  val testUri: Uri = uri"http://test.pl" //we can still use uri interpolator from http4s

}
```

But this still wouldn't compile:

```
import org.http4s.Uri
import org.http4s.syntax.AllSyntax
import com.comcast.ip4s._

class MyApp extends AllSyntax {

  val testUri: Uri = uri"http://test.pl"
  val ip = ipv4"192.168.1.1" / 24 //compile error

}
```

Unfortunately, `ip4s` doesn't provide any trait to bring implicits into scope, so we could prioritize them.

What you could do is creating another object, where you'd copy internals of package object `com.comcast.ip4s` and then extend AllSyntax:

```
import org.http4s.Uri
import org.http4s.syntax.AllSyntax
import com.comcast.ip4s._
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object MySyntax extends AllSyntax {

  //copied from com.comcast.ip4s
  final implicit class IpLiteralSyntax(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
    def ip(args: Any*): IpAddress = macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipInterpolator
    def ipv4(args: Any*): Ipv4Address =
    macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipv4Interpolator
    def ipv6(args: Any*): Ipv6Address =
    macro LiteralSyntaxMacros.ipv6Interpolator
    (...)
  }

}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
class MyApp extends App {

  import MySyntax._

  val testUri: Uri = uri"http://test.pl"
  val ip = ipv4"192.168.1.1" / 24 //interpolator from com.comcast.ip4s has higher priority

}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a cleaver trick I wasn't aware of. Maybe in Dotty there is. Thanks